# Search for a full phrase in SQL FREETEXT using CONTAINS

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I am trying to query a table with a phrase and get results that fully match my phrase. For example if I search for

```
WHERE CONTAINS(prc.SectionContent, '"check this"')
```

I get results that contain the specific words too.

I would like it it behave like a wildcard search such as:

```
WHERE SectionContent LIKE '%check this%'
```

which returns results that have the full phrase *only*.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server and MSM

Comment: The wildcard search doesn't give you what you want?

Comment: It does but it takes about 0.6 seconds on average to execute whilst FREETEXT executes in 0.05 on average. This really makes a difference for my application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FREETEXT queries in SQL Server 2008 not phrase matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462875/freetext-queries-in-sql-server-2008-not-phrase-matching)

Comment: OP from that thread is using FREETEXT which returns results that contain individual words as well as phrases. Suggested solution asks OP to use CONTAIN instead which is what I'm doing however, it is still returning some results with individual words as well as full phrases in some instances.

Comment: @RobbieDee Your CONTAINS example should have worked. Placing multiple words within double quotes, like you did, should yield results that contain the exact phrase "check this" within its text. Can you give an example where this didn't happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try using;

```
WHERE SectionContent LIKE 'check this'
```

If you remove the % (wildcards) it will search just the text.